# Context Menu Separator is not stretch horizontally inside datatemplate in wpf

Tags: c#

I have used Context Menu in my application, the separator is not stretch horizontally inside the datatemplate. The separator is center aligned and not extended upto the stackpanel end. my code is as below, And i have attached the screenshot,

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuItem" x:Name="menu" ItemsSource="{Binding Notifications}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-30,0,-50,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                            
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Image Source="Resources/Icon.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,5,0"
                           Visibility="{Binding note, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">                               
                    </Image>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestDate}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" - " Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>                      
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyOne}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="/" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyTwo}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="10"/>                     
                </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue"/>                                
                    </StackPanel>                            
                </StackPanel>                      
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"  Click="ToolBar_Click">
                        <Image Source="Resources/[![enter image description here][1]][1]Icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                                
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>                        
            </Grid>
                <Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
            </StackPanel>                    
        </DataTemplate>                  
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>           
</ContextMenu>
```

[image: Please find the ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Your Separator IS fully stretched to the size of the parent (StackPanel). The impression you have is because the grid above has negative margins: `<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-30,0,-50,0">` which makes the grid to flow outside the parent StackPanel.